# How to improve time complexity for a java recursion implementation with big numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have recursion

```
T(1) = 2 ^ k
T(2) = 2 * T(1) - 1
T(3) = 2 * T(2) - 1
T(4) = 2 * T(3) - 2
T(5) = 2 * T(4) - 4
T(6) = 2 * T(5) - 8
```

..

```
T(10) = 2 * T(9) - 128
```

..

for n >= 3 we can see that:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n-1) - (2 ^ (n-3))
```

conditions:

```
1 <= n <= 2.000.000.000
0 <= K <= 40
k < n
```

Because n can be very big I implemented this recursion by iteration with BigInteger (recursively function return StackOverflow error), but for n = 200.000 and k = 39 program takes 15 seconds to calculate T(n) and it must takes less then 5 seconds for max(n) and max(k). What I need is not T(n), but T(n) % 40009 so how can I reduce this recursion?

Comment: Hm....smells like dynamic programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets try to transform the term:

```
T(1) = 2 ^ k
T(2) = 2 * 2 ^ k - 1
T(3) = 2 * 2 * 2 ^ k - 2 * 1 - 1 = 2 ^ 2 * 2 ^ k - 2 ^ 1 - 1
T(4) = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 ^ k - 2 * 2 * 1 - 2 = 2 ^ 3 * 2 ^ k - 2 ^ 2 - 2 ^ 1
T(5) = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 ^ k - 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 - 2 * 2 - 4 = 2 ^ 4 * 2 ^ k - 2 ^ 3 - 2 ^ 2 - 2 ^ 2
T(6) = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 ^ k - 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 - 2 * 2 * 2 - 2 * 4 - 8 = 2 ^ 5 * 2 ^ k - 2 ^ 4 - 2 ^ 3 - 2 ^ 3 - 2 ^ 3
```

as you can see, we can split it into 2 terms:
first:

```
T(n) = 2 ^ (n-1) * 2 ^ k + ... = 2 ^ (k + n - 1) + ...
```

second:

```
T(n) = ... + -2^(n-2) - (n - 2) * 2^(n-3)
```

so you can calculate the term without recursion by:

```
T(n) = 2^(k + n - 1) - 2^(n-2) - (n - 2) * 2^(n-3)
```

you can then factorize the term and apply modulo to reduce numbers:

```
T(n) = 2^(n - 3) * (2^(k + 2) - 2^(1) - (n - 2)) = 2^(n - 3) * (2^(k + 2) - n)
```

now you can apply modulo:

```
T(n) modulo 40009 = ((2^(n - 3) modulo 40009) * (2^(k + 2) - n) modulo 40009) modulo 40009
```

here is implementation with BigInteger:

```
static long calc(int n, int k, int m) {
    BigInteger left = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger nBig = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n - 3));
    BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(m));
    left = left.modPow(nBig, mod);

    BigInteger right = new BigInteger("2");
    right = right.pow(k + 2);
    right = right.subtract(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n)));
    right = right.mod(mod);

    left = left.multiply(right);
    left = left.mod(mod);

    return left.longValue();
}
```

EDIT:
added initial transformation

Comment: since BigInteger is Immutable it's unneccessary to create left and right separately with the same value.

Comment: but for recursion T(n) = 2*T(n-1) - T(n-k-2) how can improve?

Comment: you can't improve recursion, you have to transfer the recursion. After the transformation you can apply modulo, modulo is actually the important part in my answer, modulo will improve the calculation time. if you will try to execute my transformation without modulo, you will have execution time > 5 sec